# Question about the definition of complex differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question about complex differentiability, or to be more precise about its definition.

> Definition:
>
> A function $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is complex differentiable in
> $c \in D$, if there exists a in $c$ continuous function
> $f_1 : D  \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, such that $f(z)=f(c)+(z-c)f_1(c)$ for all
> $z \in D$ ($\mathbb{C}$-linearization)
>
> This function $f_1$ is then uniquely determined by $f$:
>
> $f_1(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(c)}{z-c}$ for every $z \in$ D\{$z$} (Difference
> quotient)
>
> Because of the continuity of $f_1$ in $c$,define $h:=z-c$, then:
> $lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}=f_1(c)$  (differential
> quotient)

I am a little bit confused about the function $f_1$.

In real analysis I learned that a function $f$ is (real) differentiable in $c$ if
$f(c+h)-f(c)=ah+r(h)$ such that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{r(h)}{h}=0$, then a is called the differential of f in c (i.e $a=f'(c)$).

I just can't make the connection between those two definitions. And I am not sure what was meant by $\mathbb{C}$-linearisatzion.

Comment: They are equivalent, and if it makes you more comfortable then you can just use your real-analysis definition in the complex case as well.

Comment: Also, do you mean $f(z)=f(c)+(z-c)f_1(\color{red}z)$?

Comment: @Arthur Yes that should be $f(z)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rewrite the real analysis definition a little. Using $h=x-c$ to get rid of $h$ yields
$$
f(x)-f(c)=a(x-c)+r(x-c)\\
f(x)=f(c)+a(x-c)+\frac{r(x-c)}{x-c}(x-c)\\
f(x)=f(c)+(x-c)\left(a+\frac{r(x-c)}{x-c}\right)
$$
Note that $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{r(x-c)}{x-c}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{r(h)}{h}=0$ means that the contents of the rightmost bracket can be extended to a function that's continuous at $x=c$, and whose value at that point is $a$. We can call that function $f_1$, and we write
$$
f(x)=f(c)+(x-c)f_1(x)
$$
This should start to look a little familiar.

In summary, your complex definition amalgamates $a$ and $r$ into a single term it calls $f_1$, compared to the real definition which keeps them separate.

The linearization lies in the term $a(x-c)$ along with $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{r(x-c)}{x-c}=0$. Which is to say that close to $c$, $f$ is well approximated by the linear function $f(c)+(x-c)a$. The $\Bbb C$ in "$\Bbb C$-linearization" means that $a$ can take on any complex number as value.

The fact that the complex definition hides $a$ and $r$ away inside the more complicated function $f_1$ can indeed make the meaning of that term a bit difficult to decode.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful. One Question, how do I get from $f_1(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(c)}{z-c}$ to $lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h+c)-f(c)}{h}$. Where does the limit come from? If I use $h=z-c$ I get the term, but without a limit.

Comment: We have $f_1(c)=a$. And since $f_1$ is continuous at $c$ we must have $\lim_{h\to 0}f_1(c+h)=a$. Now just substitute $f_1(c+h)$ for $\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$ in that expression, since the two are equal everywhere except at $c$.

Comment: Thank You very much!